Spring framework 5.3.30, throws exception missing session attribute on post?
We have this issue in our @Post controllers With method annotations containing at @ModelAttribute. The controller has an at @SessionAttributes annotation. The model is setup oin the @Get method of the control and put in a ModelAndView.
If the post is successful due to a save or a cancel, the session status is set to complete.
When the user issues the first post, if the post contains validation errors It returns to the page with a redirect set to null .   No issue.
The second time the form is posted there are no errors and the form is posted and saved, & is removed from session and the user is redirected back to a menu page.
If the user presses the back button, the browser asks if the page needs to be resubmitted. The user resubmits the page and that model attribute for the post is no longer there, and it throws a missing sessionnattribute exception.
The error is incurring in modelfactory.findmodel,  The version of spring framework is 5.3.30. We did not experience this behavior before in an earlier Spring version, maybe spring 3.2.28.
It definitely seems broken and the repost is Actually trying to post the same data as the first set that had errors.  I didn’t think a post redirect would have an option to hit the back button and allow the user repost the form?
Ideas  ?
It only appears in these scenarios where the same submit button resulted it two outcomes: 1. It stayed on the page with errors or 2. It posted the data and went to the calling page.
